# How to (deep) copy a string in Go?

Tags: go

I should probably explain why would I want that first.

I understand in Go substring(`s[i:j]`) and `string.Split` and some other string operations work *in-place*: the resulting substrings share the same memory block of the original string.

For example I read a large string, parse and get a few substrings from it, which will be kept in the long run in a server program, they will "hold" the large memory block from GC, wasting memory. I assume if I could make a copy of those substrings and keep those copies instead, GC could free that large string.

But I can't find a string copy mechanism in Go, I tried converting it to `[]byte` then `string` again, memory usage dropped roughly 3/4 in my particular use case.

But this doesn't feel right:
1st, it introduces two copy operations.
2nd, since I never really write to that byte slice, I suspect it might got optimized out in release builds.

I can't imagine this hasn't been asked before, but my search doesn't yield any relevant results, or is there some better practices to do these kinds of things in Go?

BTW I tried to append an empty string(`+""`) to it, memory consumption doesn't drop, I assume it got optimized out even in test builds.

For measuring memory usage, I call `runtime.GC()` then `runtime.ReadMemStats()` and compare `MemStats.Alloc`, which seems pretty consistent in my tests.

Comment: I would suggest you to read up on copy function and string Builder

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava AFAIK the builtin copy works on slice, not string, or do you mean it could be used to prevent that `string([]byte())` workaround been optimized out by introducing another copy operation? strings.Builder seems unnecessarily heavy for this use case.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Go, so there is no scenario in which you should ever need to explicitly deep-copy a string; and in fact, the runtime would be permitted to override any code that attempted to do so and re-use the same string in memory anyway.

Comment: @Adrian There is no reason to deep copy a string by the specification, but there is from an implementation perspective.  The question describes a scenario where deep copy reduces memory use for an application. The compiler can optimize away all attempts to deep copy a string, but that's what the question is about: What is an efficient deep copy that the compiler retains?

Comment: What you're talking about isn't a deep copy; that would be a copy of all the data. The method of slicing a string to a byte slice then converting that to a string is the most straightforward, and the only way to do what you're describing; all other methods will do exactly this under the hood, but will be more complicated and likely less efficient.

Comment: @Adrian  The two answers ensure that the bytes are copied at most one time.  The double conversion `string([]byte(s))` can copy the bytes twice.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your substrings (resulting from strings.Split)?

Comment: @LarsKarlslund what do you mean by duplicates exactly?

Comment: Let's say you read in a lot of folder names, and you split these. For instance C:\Windows, C:\Windows\System32, C:\Windows\System32\Drivers etc. etc. If you split on backslash, and save this in slices (provided you solve your specific allocation problem described), you will still end up with multiple copies of "Windows" as a string. I don't know your use case?

Comment: @LarsKarlslund and how does that affect my question?

Comment: The new `strings.Clone(s)` function will come in handy, starting Go 1.18. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972665/6309)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The alternative would be, starting with go 1.20 (Q4 2022):

```
sCopy := strings.Clone(s)
```

It comes from issues [40200](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40200) and [45038](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45038), and starts in CLs (change lists) [334884](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/334884/) and [345849](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/345849/)

> ### bytes, strings: add Clone
>
> Working directly with `[]byte` and `string` are common and needing to copy
> them comes up fairly often.
> This change adds a `Clone` helper to both strings and bytes to fill this need.
> A benchmark was also added to provide evidence for why `bytes.Clone` was implemented with `copy`.
>
> ### strings: add Clone function
>
> The new `strings.Clone` function copies the input string without the returned cloned string referencing the input strings memory

See [`strings/clone.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/strings/clone.go)

```golang
// Clone returns a fresh copy of s.
// It guarantees to make a copy of s into a new allocation,
// which can be important when retaining only a small substring
// of a much larger string. Using Clone can help such programs
// use less memory. Of course, since using Clone makes a copy,
// overuse of Clone can make programs use more memory.
// Clone should typically be used only rarely, and only when
// profiling indicates that it is needed.
// For strings of length zero the string "" will be returned
// and no allocation is made.
func Clone(s string) string {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    b := make([]byte, len(s))
    copy(b, s)
    return unsafe.String(&b[0], len(b))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

String in go are immutable once created. Go [specs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types)

I will prefer builder as below. You go on adding to buffer of builder (mutably) `WriteString`  and once done call `String` method which is returning pointer and not another copy of the buffer slice.

```
    somestring := "Hello Go"
    var sb strings.Builder
    if _, err := sb.WriteString(somestring); err != nil {
        //log & return
    }
    newstring := sb.String()
```

Check the implementation of String() of builder from go source. It is returning pointer and cast as *string. No second copy.

```
// String returns the accumulated string.
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b.buf))
}
```

Comment: While this currently works, there is no guarantee that future versions might not optimize this away.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following function to deep copy a string:

```
func deepCopy(s string) string {
    b := make([]byte, len(s))
    copy(b, s)
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
}
```

The function copies the data to a newly allocated slice of bytes. The function uses the unsafe package to convert the slice header to a string header with no copying of the bytes.

If direct use of the unsafe package is a concern, then use [strings.Builder](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder). The strings.Builder type executes the unsafe shenanigans [under the covers](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/98a73030b01cc23a292934d09f137a2befa439bf/src/strings/builder.go#L48).

```
 func deepCopy(s string) string {
     var sb strings.Builder
     sb.WriteString(s)
     return sb.String()
 }
```

There's no need to check the error returned from sb.WriteString. The [Builder.WriteString](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder.WriteString) method has an error return so that the Builder type satisfies the  [io.StringWriter](https://godoc.org/io#StringWriter) interface, not because WriteString can return a non-nil error.

Comment: Good answer (upvoted), but keep in mind that `unsafe` does not work on all platforms/implementations.

Answer (score 4):

The string is implemented as a pointer to the underlying byte array and the length of the string. When you create a slice from an existing string, the new string still points to the underlying array, possibly to a different offset in that array, with a different length. That way, many small strings can use the single underlying large array.

As you noted, if you have a large string and you parse it to get smaller strings, you end up keeping the large string in memory, because the GC only knows about the underlying array and pointers to it. There are two ways you can deal with this:

- Instead of a large string, keep a `[]byte` or use a byte-stream based reader/scanner, and as you parse create strings from the input. That way GC will collect the underlying `[]byte` when parsing is done and you will have your strings without the underlying large block.
- Do what you already described, and deep-copy string using `string([]byte(s[x:y]))`, or by using `copy`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of cloning a string is to create a new one by concatenation with non-empty string, this will allocate a new underlying buffer, and then take a substring of a result:

```
cloned := (s + ".")[:len(s)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func Sub(pStr string, pFrom, pTo int) string {
    // Sub("alfa",0,1)="a"; Sub("alfa",1,3)="lf"; Sub("alfa",0,0)="alfa"; Sub("alfa",2,0)="fa"; Sub("alfa",2,999)="fa";
    c := len(pStr)
    if c == 0 || pFrom < 0 {
        return ""
    }
    if pTo == 0 && pFrom == 0 {
        return pStr
    }
    t := ""
    if pTo < pFrom || pTo >= c {
        t = pStr[pFrom:]
    } else {
        t = pStr[pFrom:pTo]
    }
    return strings.Clone(t)
}
```

Comment: It's incorect! You make slices that based on the same raw chars, it won't be a deep copy.

Comment: Yes thank You, but I modified this function, add strings.Clone(t)