# Will the original string be freed if I return a portion of it in a function?

Tags: string, go

I have learned that when using square braces to take a portion of a string, Go will not create a new string, instead it reflects the same underlying string, similar to a slice.

So in the following function, does the return portion from the function prevent the original string from being released and cause a memory leak?

```golang
func Slice(str string, start int, end int) string {
    limit := len(str)

    if start < 0 {
        start = limit + start
    }

    if end < 0 {
        end = limit + end
    }

    if end > limit {
        end = limit
    }

    if start >= end || start >= limit {
        return "" // return an empty string directly
    }

    return str[start:end]
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65419268/how-to-deep-copy-a-string-in-go/68972665#68972665

Comment: No because that is not an actual leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When slicing a string, the result substring will share memory with the original. This also means the original string will be kept in memory.

Is this considered a memory leak? Depends. Usually a memory leak indicates increasing memory usage, and in this case memory usage will not grow, it's just some things may be kept in memory which you actually don't need / use anymore.

If you know you're slicing a big string and the rest of the string is not needed, you may make a copy of the result to not retain a reference to the original big string using [`strings.Clone()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Clone) like this:

```
return strings.Clone(str[start:end])
```

Quoting from the doc of `strings.Clone()`:

> Clone returns a fresh copy of s. **It guarantees to make a copy of s into a new allocation, which can be important when retaining only a small substring of a much larger string. Using Clone can help such programs use less memory.**